# in excel (using Python or excel): search if the content of a cell (string) is contained (substring) in other cells

Tags: python, excel, string, substring

I have a column in excel with product names (about 40,000 cells, containing strings). For each cell (A1), I want to know:
- if the content of this cell (string in A1: protein B) is found as a substring in one or more other cells of the column (A1 to A40000)
- and in which ones (ex: A14: protein B2, A270: eye protein B-270, A8088: protein B yeast homolog).

I want do do that for each cells (check if A2 content found as substring in column A, check if A3....)

I know how to execute Python code but don't know much (yet) about coding

Comment: If you don't know enough to write code yet, then it's too early to be asking question like this here...S.O. is not a tutorial site.

Answer (score 0):

If the information you're searching for is consistently at the beginning of each value in the search range (e.g. "protien B[variable1]", "protein B[variable2]", "protein B[variable3]"), you could insert a new column and use the LEFT function to extract the first 9 characters (in the case of Protein B).  You could then use the MATCH function to find the first occurrence of "Protein B" in that range.  There's also a more complicated method to find the nth occurrence of a value in a range: https://exceljet.net/formula/get-nth-match-with-index-match

You could also use COUNTIF to find the number of occurrences of "Protein B" in your new range.

This method won't work if the string you're searching for is in the middle of a larger string. e.g. it won't work searching for "Protein B" in "ABC Protein B Yeast homolog").